# Unable to put subquery condition in case when statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, `seat` and need to print some data as per the given conditions. I am unable to execute the query because of a syntax error which is never descriptive and I am unable to deduce the reason behind it.

This is my query generating the syntax error:

```
select (case id when mod(id, 2)=0 then id=id+1 
                when mod(id,2) <> 0 and id != (select count(*) from seat) then id=id-1 
                else id=id) as id, 
       student 
from seat;
```

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as id, student from seat' at line 2

The task is to switch the values(of a particular column) of adjacent rows. Complete problem is available [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/exchange-seats/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the output variable in the values in your `CASE` expression. Also you should not specify an input to the `CASE` when you use logical expressions in the `WHEN` conditions, and you are missing an `END` to the `CASE`. Try this instead:

```
select case when mod(id, 2) =  0 then id-1 
            when mod(id, 2) <> 0 and id != (select count(*) from seat) then id+1
            else id
       end as id, 
       student 
from seat
order by id;
```

Output (for the leetcode question)

```
id  student
1   Doris
2   Abbot
3   Green
4   Emerson
5   Jeames
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tsvF9TFRvDE1VkH6KUc9uZ/2)

Comment: why `then 0`? shouldn't it be `id+1` instead?

Comment: @AviralSrivastava I just copied the values from your expression...

Comment: Oh sorry, I am updating it. My bad.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava note that you shouldn't have `id` as an input to the case expression either; you would only do that if you are comparing the value of `id` against fixed values e.g. `case id when 2 then x when 3 then y ...`

Comment: @AviralSrivastava I've added a working demo for you.

Comment: Hey Nick, thank you so much. I noticed that your ans(working demo) is accepted but mine was rejected. The only difference was that I was using `case id when...` whereas you are using `case when ....`

So, is this what you were saying about I shouldn't have `id` as an input to the case expression either?
Can you elaborate or point me to the some reading material?

Comment: @AviralSrivastava yes that's what the problem is. Here's a [link to the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) describing case expressions, as you will see there are two formats, the one I have used in the answer and the one I talked about in the comment.

Comment: Thank you so much, not just for the answer but more importantly, patiently directing me towards conceptual stuff.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava No worries. There's also a pretty good tutorial [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/)